# Combine multiple split panes into single window with tabs in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, rider, splitpane

I have multiple tabs in multiple panes, but when I've move from my widescreen to my laptop, the panes no longer works well at half-width.

Can I keep all the existing files open, but move/merge/combine them into a single pane? *(Without having to drag each of the tabs individually?)*

[image: split panes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to [Editor Basics](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-code-editor.html#manage_tabs):

> To unsplit the screen, from the context menu, select `Unsplit` or `Unsplit All` to unsplit all the split frames.

Go to `Window` > `Editor Tabs` > `Unsplit`

[image]